# The 'Save-Module' command was found in the module 'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: windows, powershell, powershellget

When I execute the command at power shell  `Save-Module -Name ACMESharp -Path <path>`

It prompts the error as below:

**The 'Save-Module' command was found in the module 'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be loaded.**

Then I try to execute  `Import-Module PowerShellGet`  turn out that it was the execution policy problems that the status is "restricted" the script.

Answer (score 2):

To check whether is about the execution policy , you could just try to execute the ps command `Get-ExecutionPolicy`

if is return result show is restricted then you have to change the execution policy to RemoteSigned. 
**PS: hope that it won't cause any security issue. Just In case ,disable it after you done.**

To disable the restriction, I just execute the ps Command below.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

To change /remove the execution policy

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Undefined
```

Or, type:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Undefined -scope LocalMachine
```

For more information can visit the link below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Execution_Policies